# Indy support for current OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, indy

Have there been any Indy roadmap announcements concerning updates to Indy to support the new OpenSSL API?

I tried to use CrossVCL to deploy a formerly Win32/64 app to native linux; I ran into the problem of Indy's TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL not supporting the current version of the OpenSSL binaries for linux.

I ended up having to switch to TNetHTTPClient from TIdHttp. This works fine on linux, however I still needed to use TIdHttpServer for other functions in the app; it works fine as long as I don't use SSL. Which isn't viable for most situations.

Answer (score 0):

> Have there been any Indy roadmap announcements concerning updates to Indy to support the new OpenSSL API?

No, it is still a work-in-progress. The majority of Indy's existing OpenSSL code was written by JP, who is no longer involved with Indy.  The latest PR code for OpenSSL 3.x is available at https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299 and mostly works.  It was submitted by mezen, who has said that he wants to abandon that PR and make something new with the latest OpenSSL release.  So Indy's support for OpenSSL 3.x is still in flux.  I haven't been able to work on the PR myself in a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Remy. If you get to work on it will you provide an update?